# Number of numbers always have a predifined digit in its decimal presentation

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Can anyone prove or disprove this:
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {\sum_ {i=0}^{n-1} 9^i \binom {n}{n-i}}{10^n}=1$

Note: the numerator of the fraction above is the number of numbers up to $10^n$ which always have at least one predifined digit(for example 7) in its decimal presentation.

Comment: It may be easier to prove that the proportion of numbers less than $10^n$ that contain no $7$s tends to zero...

Comment: Both statements are equivalent. I don't think there's difference in the difficulty.

Comment: With respect I don't think it is as easy as you stated

Comment: There are $9$ possible digits in each of the $n$ positions since we can choose any of $$\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9\}$$thus there must be $9^n$ choices. It's also possible to simplify the stated problem using the binomial theorem. The numerator is simply$$(1+9)^n-9^n$$

Comment: You're right, amazingly the reverse is much more simplified. Great

Comment: It's somehow like the famous Gauss's solution sum of $1+2+...+100$